# Divide two columns in different MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage, divide

I have two different tables where I would like to calculate the percentage (5/10-1) between these two values.

```
    Table: First day
    Column: Price
    Value: 10

    Table: Last_day
    Column: Price
    Value: 5
```

I am a bit new to SQL and have seen some examples but not when the values are in different tables, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Very strange db design. Why do you have different tables for different days?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Can you include a more complete DB design of yours? This DB scheme is honestly a little weird to me.

Comment: It's an example and that is why it might look weird, but it illustrates the issue quite well.

Comment: Give the sample data in a tabular format!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
SELECT a.price as 'first_day price',b.price as 'last_day price',
  concat( round( ( (a.price -b.price)/b.price * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
  FROM first_day a, last_day b
```

Here's an sqlfiddle for this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e62d5/3

Comment: Thanks, we are getting closer! The percentage is off however, first price and last price 10 should not result in 100% increase. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Ok, now it calculates increase percentage